# Database Modeling: How to catogorize products like Amazon?

Tags: mysql, relational-database, database-design

Assume I had a number of products (from a few thousands to hundred of thousands) that needed to be categorized in a hierarchical manner. **How would I model such a solution in a database?**

Would a simple parent-child table like this work:

```
product_category
- id
- parent_id
- category_name
```

Then in my products table, I would just do this:

```
product
- id
- product_category_id
- name
- description
- price
```

My concern is that this won't scale. By the way, I'm using MySQL for now.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPTT

Comment: Check out the http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/ for organising the categories in a hierarchical fashion This would allow you to avoid joins when getting hierarchies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Course it will scale.  That will work just fine, it is a commonly used structure.

Include a `level_no`.  That will assist in the code, but  more important, it is required to exclude duplicates.

If you want a really tight structure, you need something like the Unix concept of inodes.

You may have difficulty getting your head around the code required to produce the hierarchy, say from a `product`, but that is a separate issue.

And please change

- (`product_category`)) `id`  to  `product_category_id`
- (`product` `id` to `product_id`
- `parent_id` to `parent_product_category_id`

**Responses to Comments**

1. `level_no`. Have a look at this Data Model, it is for a Directory Tree structure (eg. the FlieManager Explorer window):

   [**Directory Data Model**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Andrew%20DM.pdf)

   See if you can make sense of it, that's the Unix inode concept. The FileNames have to be unique within the Node, hence the second Index.  That is actually complete, but some developers these days will have a hissy fit writing the code required to navigate the hierarchy, the levels.  Those developers need a `level_no` to identify what level in the hierarchy they are dealing with.
2. Recommended changes.  Yes, it is called Good Naming Conventions.  I am rigid about it, and I publish it, so it is a Naming Standard.  There are reasons for it, which will become clear to you when you write some SQL with 3 or 4 levels of joins; especially when you go to same one parent two different ways.  If you search SO, you will find many questions for this; always the same answer.  It will also be highlit in the next model I write for you.

Comment: can you explain a bit more the purpose of `level_no`? Also, the recommended changes you mentioned, are they aligned with some sort of coding convention?

Comment: @SONewbie. Answered in my post.

Answer (score 3):

I used to struggle with the same problem 10 years ago. Here's my personal solution to this problem. But before I start explaining, I would like to mention its pros and cons.

**Pros:**

1. You can select subbranches of a given node within any number of
   desired depths, with the lowest imaginable cost.
2. The same can be done to select parent nodes.
3. No RDBMS specific feature is needed. So the same technique can be
   implemented in any of them.
4. It is all implemented using a single field.

**Cons:**

1. You should be able to define a maximum number of depth for your
   tree. You also need to define the maximum number of direct children
   for the nodes.
2. Restructuring the tree is more expensive than traversing it. But not
   as expensive as [Nest Set Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). Adding a new branch is the matter of
   finding the right value for the field. And in order to move a branch
   into a new parent you need to update that node and all its children
   (direct and indirect). The good news is that deleting a node and its
   children is as easy as traversing it (which is absolutely nothing).

**The technique:**

Consider the following table as your tree holder:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_category` (
  `product_category_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `category_code` varchar(62) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_category_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uni_category_code` (`category_code`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

All the magic is done in `category_code` field. You need to encode your branch address into a text value as follow:

```
**node_name -> category_code**
Root -> 01
First child -> 01:01
Second child -> 01:02
First grandchild -> 01:01:01
First child of second child -> 01:02:01
```

In the above example, each node can have up to 99 direct children (assuming we are thinking in decimal). And since `category_code` is of type `varchar(62)`, we can have up to (62-2)/3 = 20 depth. It's a trade off between the depth you want and the number of direct children each node can have and the size of your field. Scientifically speaking, this is an implementation of a [complete tree](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/completetree.html) in which unused branches are not actually created but reserved.

**The good parts:**

Now imagine you want to select nodes under `01:02`. You can do this using a single query:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_category
WHERE
   category_code LIKE '01:02:%'
```

Selecting direct nodes under the `01:02`:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_category
WHERE
   category_code LIKE '01:02:__'
```

Selecting all the ancestors of `01:02`:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_category
WHERE
   '01:02' LIKE CONCAT(category_code, ':%')
```

**The bad parts:**

Inserting a new node into the tree is the matter of finding the right `category_code`. This can be done using a stored procedure or even in a programming language like PHP.

Since the tree is limited in the number of direct children and depth, an insert can fail. But I believe in most practical cases we can assume such a limitation.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution uses the adjacency list model of a hierarchy.  It's by far the most common.  It will scale ok up to thousands of products.  The problem is that it takes either a recursive query or product specific extensions to SQL to deal with an indefinitely deep hierarchy.

There are other models of a hierarchy.  In particular, there's the nested set model.  The nested set model is good for retrieving the path of any node in a single query.  It's also good for retrieving any desired sub tree.  It's more work to keep it up to date.  A lot more work.

You may want to briefly explore it before you bite off more than you want to chew.

What are you going to do with the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

I think your big issue is that this is a deficiency in MySQL.  For most RDBMSs which support WITH and WITH RECURSIVE, you should require only one scan per level.  This makes deep hierarchies a bit problematic but usually not too bad.

I think to make this work well you will have to code a fairly extensive stored procedure, or you will have to go to another tree model, or you will have to move to a different RDBMS.  For example this is easy to do with PostgreSQL and WITH RECURSIVE and this offers a lot better scalability than many other approaches.